# mvc 2.0 xval Validation summary for two controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xval

I got small problem with validation summary :

When I have two two control on page all summary validation information goes to first control validation summary element, even xval generated script say that elementID are different for summary.
Any one know how to repair it?

Here is link for sample project http://www.sendspace.com/file/m9gl54  .

Answer (score 0):

OK it was my bad copy paste to sample project. So problem is resolved.